# Python. Selenium. drag_and_drop error 'AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Tell me please, what am I doing wrong?
I try to drag and drop through Selenium, but every time I come across an error "AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement"

**Here is my code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chromedriver = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/drag-drop-custom/demo-drag-drop-3.html')

source = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="box3"]')
target = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="box103"]')

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.drag_and_drop(source, target).perform()
```

**I also tried, like this:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chromedriver = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/drag-drop-custom/demo-drag-drop-3.html')

source = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="box3"]')
target = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="box103"]')
ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(source).move_to_element(target).release(target).perform()
```

**Always coming out "AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement"**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "drag_and_drop_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(source).move_to_element(target).release(target).perform()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 121, in click_and_hold
    self.move_to_element(on_element)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 273, in move_to_element
    self.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_to(to_element)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/actions/pointer_actions.py", line 42, in move_to
    raise AttributeError("move_to requires a WebElement")
AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find_elements_by_xpath` returns a list of `WebElement`s, `drag_and_drop` (and the other methods) accept a single `WebElement`. Use `find_element_by_xpath`

```
source = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="box3"]')
target = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="box103"]')
```

Comment: Guy, Hello! Thanks for your reply! Yes, the real problem was that I chose 'find_elements_by_xpath', but it was necessary 'find_element_by_xpath'. Good experience, I will know

Answer (score 2):

as @guy said:

```
find_elements_by_xpath
```

returns list of `WebElements`. You can use `find_element_by_xpath` method to get single web element. Or select specific element from `WebElements` return by `find_elements_by_xpath`. For example, if you know, you wanted to select 2nd element from return list for target. Then you can try like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chromedriver = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/drag-drop-custom/demo-drag-drop-3.html')

source = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="box3"]')[0]
target = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="box103"]')[1]

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.drag_and_drop(source, target).perform()
```

i can see we are selecting element which have id but ids are unique, so there can be only one id. So you can also do this like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chromedriver = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/drag-drop-custom/demo-drag-drop-3.html')

source = driver.find_element_by_id('box3')
target = driver.find_element_by_id('box103')

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.drag_and_drop(source, target).perform()
```

i like to use `find_element_by_id` because it looks cleaner to me than xpath.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement
```

...implies that the `move_to_element()` requires a *WebElement* as an argument.

Seems you were close. You have used `find_elements_by_xpath()` which returns a *List* where as you need pass a *WebElement* within `move_to_element()`.

### Solution

To *drag* the element with text as **Washington** and *drop* within the element with text as **United States** through [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get('http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/drag-drop-custom/demo-drag-drop-3.html')
  source = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='dragableBox' and @id='box3']")))
  target = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='dragableBoxRight' and @id='box103']")))
  ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(source).move_to_element(target).release(target).perform()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: drag_and_drop]

Answer (score 0):

use `find_elements_by_xpath` instead `find_element_by_xpath`