# Selenium driver Python drag and drop, element is dropped where is pointer and not dropping area

Tags: python, selenium, automation

The drag action is working, but instead of drop in the selected area, drop on mouse pointer position. Someone has any idea? Thanks

```
def test_drag_action_to_tsb(self, driver):
    source_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bzm-action-builder-tabs-tabpane-ACTION"]/ul/li[1]')
    base.wait_for_element(driver, By.CLASS_NAME, 'scriptless-scenarios-steps-panel')
    dest_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name(self, 'scriptless-scenarios-steps-panel')
    ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(source_element).move_to_element(dest_element).release(dest_element).perform()
    time.sleep(5)
    assert base.is_text_present(driver, 'is Required')
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Please share HTML of Source and destination element with error if you are getting

Comment: no errors and dest_element exist because I check for it (wait_for_element)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59603918/selenium-actions-draganddrop-unexpectedly-navigates-to-google-search-page/59604483?noredirect=1#comment105373442_59604483) is same issue, not solved.

Comment: Is the source element above or below the destination element?

Comment: is on the left side, same z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on [selenium documentation](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) following codes should work :

```
ActionChains(driver). drag_and_drop(source_element, dest_element).perform()
```

Comment: build() is not available according the documentation

Comment: Sorry, I updated the answer. did you tried it without build? @Morticella

Comment: it was the first version that I used, but doesn't works :(