# Selenium Python, element is dropped at the pointer location and not into destination

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to perform drag and drop with Selenium Chrome driver in Python using

```
source = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//test-card")
destination = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//test-folder")
ActionChains(self.driver).drag_and_drop(source, destination).perform()
```

but the element is dropped at the pointer location and not at the destination location. Here the same issue: [Selenium driver Python drag and drop, element is dropped where is pointer and not dropping area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59735440/selenium-driver-python-drag-and-drop-element-is-dropped-where-is-pointer-and-no/61819956?noredirect=1#comment109345045_61819956) but not solved

Any ideas? I guess the driver needs some preference to be set up but I didn't find any useful preference to this purpose

Comment: Any chance we can see the webpage/html source/the way you defined source and destination?

Comment: I just used xpaths to find a card that is the source and a folder that is my destination, I will edit the question

Comment: @0buz the used framework is AngularJS